# help with absolute value question $||x-3|-2|\leq 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification, absolute-value

could anyone help in validating this absolute value question that my son is working on?
$|(|x-3|-2)|\leq 1$

$-1\leq|x-3|-2\leq 1$

$1\leq|x-3|\leq 3$

$1\leq x-3\leq 3$

$4\leq x\leq 6$

or

$-3\leq x-3\leq -1$

$0\leq x\leq 2$

thus

$x\in [4,6]\cup [0,2]$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: The calculation looks correct and sensibly laid out.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason his online math program isn't accepting the answer, I just wanted to make sure he did it correctly.  I can take up the formatting/input issues with his teacher.

Comment: The way you present it, it looks like you intended to say step 3 implies step 4.  Somehow you should put an "either step 4 or step 6" statement in there.  Other wise.... Um... Yeah.  Correct.

Comment: right, should have included that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks okay to me. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$